# Double slit interference of light

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment

The typical textbook explanation of the interference fringes in a double slit experiment goes like this. If the difference between the path lengths travelled by waves from each slit to a point on the screen is a whole number of wavelengths then the two waves interfere constructively at the point and we have a bright spot.

But is this right? Consider two waves which begin from the two slits in phase with the amplitudes of their electric fields equal to zero. They arrive at a point on the screen at which the difference of their path lengths is one wavelength. This also means that the difference between the time taken to reach the point is one period. So they arrive in phase at the point but since the amplitude of their electric fields is zero the point is a dark spot, not a bright spot.

What is the error in this argument?

Answer (score 0):

T/2 later you have amplitudes at max . The intensity of light is proportional to $A^2$ . when you "see" light you dont see the maxima and minima, you just get the mean energy. So as in the two slits you have at the point oscillation of the electric field with double amplitude.

Comment: At a point on the screen the amplitude does not vary with time.

Comment: You are right, I used the wrong expression, instead of maximal amplitude it should  have said maximal E, but in your post you also spoke of amplitude zero at the slits?

Comment: I said the two waves have zero amplitude at the slits only for convenience of calculation. The point is that the phase difference between waves at the two slits and at the screens is constant in time. Even if the waves are in phase with each other but have zero amplitudes at the screen you have a dark spot.  This contradicts the classical argument that a bright spot is where the path difference between the two waves is an integer number of wave lengths.

Comment: I don't understand you. If there is no amplitude, there is no wave, so no light. So if no light is coming from the slits you have no light on the screen. If you have light thru the slits you have light on the screen, when the two waves are in phase.

Comment: The slit has magnitude, so while there are points at which the amplitude of the electric field is zero, there are other points at which the amplitude is not zero. In the classical analysis of diffraction the slit is assumed to have magnitude. In the analysis of interference the slit is assumed to have zero magnitude. The interference fringes occur on the diffraction fringes. What I am suggesting is that there is something wrong with the classical analysis.

Comment: If the amplitude of the electric field is zero at the slit that does not mean there is no light. The amplitude varies sinusoidally. So there will be still be points on the screen where the amplitude of the electric field is not zero.

Comment: The E-field has an amplitude which is the maximum of |E|  so $E=A*sin(\omega t)$ at he slits and the same at the point on the screen where the waves are in the same phase, you have $E=2*A*sin(\omega t)$ it semms you are not clear about amplitude and magnitude of E at different times. at the screnn you have the same oscillation.

Comment: The amplitude at any point, whether at the slits or at the screen, must be constant in time. If the amplitude at a point on the screen was not constant in time, you would not get dark and bright fringes, just uniform illumination because of time averaging by our eyes.

Comment: I stop givin comment, just on last Try. At the slit the electric field changes  with =∗() so there are moments when E=0 and other moments when  E=A ,A is called amplitude

Comment: Let me break up my argument into points so that it is possible to narrow down the error if any. 1. A laser emits waves that are in phase. Assume that at the time of emission the electric field of each wave is zero. 2. The wave travels a fixed distance to a slit. Assume that this distance is a whole number of wavelengths. This means the wave takes a whole number of periods to reach the slit. 3. This means the electric field of the wave when it arrives at the slit will be zero always. Which of these points is incorrect?